# Apply patch file to Magento core files

Tags: php, file, patch

I edit some core code of magento. After this I would like to patch all my edited files to the Magento directory.

My question is: How can I implement php patch with magento? Or how to create patch file with PHP.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Pathfiles are great way to record & distribute you local modifications. Creating a patch file is relatively easy, and applying a patch is even easier.

Before you begin, how did you retrieve Magento's source file?

If you've checkout the source code with SVN, generating a patch is pretty simple.

```
shell $> cd path/to/your/working/copy
shell $> svn diff > ~/Desktop/magento.path
```

However, if you downloaded Magento from an archive (tar,zip), you'll need to have the copy of the original files before comparing your revisions. I like to make a original file backup, `cp source.php source.php.org`, before I alter anything. Sometimes I forget, and I'll need extract the original source-code to a new directory for comparison. To generate a patch file by comparing two sources, use the `diff` command

```
shell $> diff -Naur path/to/original/copy path/to/your/working/copy > ~/Desktop/magento.patch
```

To apply your newly created patch, use the  `patch` command.

```
shell $> cd path/to/new/magento
shell $> patch -p0 < ~/Desktop/magento.patch
```

Piece of cake.

Now your question implied that you may want PHP to apply patches. If you comfortable with compiling PHP extentions, take a look at [xdiff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php)'s [xdiff_file_patch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-patch.php) function. Else, simply run the previous commands through PHP's [system](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [shell_exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) methods.